# Electron Angular how to use localstorage

Tags: angular, typescript, electron

I downloaded [this project](https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron)

I'm using the [electron-store](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-store) module **to store data** but I don’t know how to import it within the angular project. The module works in them in the electron's `main.ts`.

**So I tried the following**:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router, private store: store) {
    console.log(store.get('unicorns'));
  }
}
```

**But I always got** `null` when testing it.
I’m sure I did something wrong. Can someone help me with this problem?